# Adding users and attributes programatically in Concrete5 version 8

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-8.x

Hi I have recently followed some documentation to create new users from a csv file programatically. According to the Concrete5 docs/api there was method called getByID( $uID ) but this has since be deprecated!

I am creating a new user like so:

```
$userRegistration = Core::make('user/registration');

$file = fopen("test-users.csv","r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
echo "email address " . $data[0];
$userRegistration->create([
'uName' => $data[0],
'uPassword' => $data[1],
'uEmail' => $data[2],
'uIsValidated' => true,
]);
}
```

However if I want to add a value to an existing non-core attribute for instance lets call it user_county then how would I change this after programatically adding the user? I may need to do this for several user attributes as well so the values would need to come from the CSV and automatically be looped through to apply the correct value to the corresponding attribute whether it is blank or filled.

Answer (score 1):

The `create()` method will return a `UserInfo` object (Concrete\Core\User\UserInfo) after successfully adding a new user. With the returned `UserInfo` object, you can use the `setAttribute()` method to set your custom user attribute.

Make sure that you have created the customer user attribute first and check that it is available before setting it, otherwise setting it will throw an error. I believe you can do this using `Concrete\Core\Attribute\Key\UserKey::getByHandle('my_user_attribute')` and seeing if it returns an object.

The create() method is in the RegistrationService class:

https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/blob/develop/concrete/src/User/RegistrationService.php#L51-L140